# Debug with XDebug, VSCode, and Docker

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I'm trying to configure XDebug in the Docker from [docker4drupal](https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal) and VSCode, I get nothingh although I have follow this:

- https://medium.com/@jasonterando/debugging-with-visual-studio-code-xdebug-and-docker-on-windows-b63a10b0dec
- https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug
- https://wodby.com/docs/stacks/drupal/local/#xdebug

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
php:
    image: wodby/drupal-php:$PHP_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_php"
    environment:
      PHP_SENDMAIL_PATH: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -S mailhog:1025
#      PHP_SENDMAIL_PATH: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -S opensmtpd:25      
      DB_HOST: $DB_HOST
      DB_PORT: $DB_PORT
      DB_USER: $DB_USER
      DB_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
      DB_NAME: $DB_NAME
      DB_DRIVER: $DB_DRIVER
      PHP_FPM_USER: wodby
      PHP_FPM_GROUP: wodby
      COLUMNS: 80 # Set 80 columns for docker exec -it.
# ## Read instructions at https://wodby.com/docs/stacks/php/local/#xdebug
      PHP_XDEBUG: 1
      PHP_XDEBUG_DEFAULT_ENABLE: 1
# #      PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_CONNECT_BACK: 0
# #      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=my-ide
      PHP_XDEBUG_IDEKEY: "VSCODE"
      PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST: host.docker.internal # Docker 18.03+ Mac/Win
# #      PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST: 172.17.0.1 # Linux
#      PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST: 10.254.254.254 # macOS, Docker < 18.03
#      PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST: 10.0.75.1 # Windows, Docker < 18.03
#      PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_LOG: /tmp/php-xdebug.log
## PHPUnit Drupal testing configurations
#      SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL: "http://nginx"
#      SIMPLETEST_DB: "${DB_DRIVER}://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASSWORD}@${DB_HOST}/${DB_NAME}#tests_"
#      MINK_DRIVER_ARGS_WEBDRIVER: '["chrome", {"browserName":"chrome","goog:chromeOptions":{"args":["--disable-gpu","--headless"]}}, "http://chrome:9515"]'

    volumes:
      - ../drupal:/var/www/html
## For macOS users (https://wodby.com/docs/stacks/drupal/local#docker-for-mac)
#      - ./:/var/www/html:cached # User-guided caching
#      - docker-sync:/var/www/html # Docker-sync
## For XHProf and Xdebug profiler traces
#      - files:/mnt/files
```

My launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "/Users/oskar/Webapps/Docker/project/drupal",
                "/var/www/html/web": "/Users/oskar/Webapps/Docker/project/drupal/web"
            },
            "xdebugSettings": {
                "max_data": 65535,
                "show_hidden": 1,
                "max_children": 100,
                "max_depth": 5
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have the launch.json in `.vscode/launch.json`

Also my structure is:

```
/Users/oskar/Webapps/Docker/project/drupal/
/Users/oskar/Webapps/Docker/project/docker/
```

When I try to run the debug I get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but since I have it working I thought I would leave tracks for others.
Here's what I had to put into my Dockerfile for the php-apache container

```
# enable xdebug
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# precreate log file for xdebug
RUN echo " " >> xdebug.log \
&& chown www-data:www-data xdebug.log \
&& chmod 774 xdebug.log \
# precreate directory for xdebug profiler
&& mkdir profiles \
&& chown www-data:www-data profiles \
&& chmod 774 profiles\
# precreate directory for xdebug tracer
&& mkdir traces \
&& chown www-data:www-data traces \
&& chmod 774 traces

# create and move xdebug.ini initialization file to start up dir
# Add Xdebug to PHP configuration
# See https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings
RUN echo "" >> xdebug.ini \
&& echo "[xdebug]" >> xdebug.ini \
&& echo "zend_extension = /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so" >> xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_enable = 1" >> xdebug.ini \
#profile setting
&& echo "xdebug.profiler_enable = 0" >> xdebug.ini \
#               use url param XDEBUG_PROFILE nothing or secret found in profile_enable_trigger_value
&& echo "xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1" >> xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.profiler_output_name = readxdebug.out.%t.pro" >> xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /usr/local/etc/php/profiles" >> xdebug.ini \
#trace setting
&& echo "xdebug.trace_enable_trigger = 1" >> xdebug.ini \
#               use url param XDEBUG_TRACE nothing or secret found in trace_enable_trigger_value
&& echo "xdebug.trace_output_name = readtrace.%c" >> xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.trace_output_dir = /usr/local/etc/php/traces" >> xdebug.ini \
#
&& echo "xdebug.remote_autostart = 1" >> xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_host = host.docker.internal" >> xdebug.ini\
&& echo "xdebug.default_enable=1" >> xdebug.ini\
&& echo "xdebug.remote_port=9000" >> xdebug.ini\
&& echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=0" >> xdebug.ini\
&& echo "xdebug.idekey=VSCODE" >> xdebug.ini\
&& echo "xdebug.remote_log=/usr/local/etc/php/xdebug.log" >> xdebug.ini\
&& mv xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
```

I configured XDEBUG to trigger profiles using url param XDEBUG_PROFILE and traces
using url param XDEBUG_TRACE.

I also use the following commands to move the profile or trace output file to a mapped directory for a given project

```
docker exec -t docker_myprojapp_1 bash -c "mv /usr/local/etc/php/profiles/*.xt /var/
www/html/projectname/dev/profiles/"

docker exec -t docker_myprojapp_1 bash -c "mv /usr/local/etc/php/traces/*.xt /var/
www/html/projectname/dev/traces/"
```